# SendBird not working with Ionic2/Angular2

Tags: angular, ionic2, sendbird

For one of my projects i needed to embed messaging functionality, i choose to go with SendBird as their documentation is good and supporting major platforms.After installing SendBird messaging sdk when i tried to import sendbird in my typescript file it throws sendbird.d.ts is not a module. I did some modification and made the interface as export in sendbird.d.ts file , when i tried to intialize sendbird it throws sendbird.new is not a constructor function. It's now is a big dilemma for me , should i go ahead with SendBird or go with some other frameworks.

```
 export interface SendBirdFactory {
  version: number; // SendBird SDK version

  new(option: Object): SendBird_Instance;
}


/**
 * Interface for the SendBird Main
 */
export interface SendBird_Instance {
}

import {SendBird,SendBirdFactory,SendBird_Instance} from 'sendbird';//import in class
this.sendbird = <SendBird_Instance>{}//inside constructor
this.sendbird.connect(this.loginForm.value.email,this.response);//inside functions
```

Answer (score 2):

You're importing the type definitions, not the actual library. Try doing:

`import * as SendBird from 'SendBird';`